# How to make list variable names into strings

Tags: python, variables

I think this should be simple but I'm not sure how to do it. I have a tuple of list variables:

```
A = (a,b,c)
```

where

```
a = [1,2,3,...]
b = [2,4,6,4,...]
c = [4,6,4,...]
```

And I want to make a tuple or list where it is the names of the variables. So,

```
A_names = ('a','b','c')
```

How could I do this? My tuple will have more variables and it is not always the same variables. I tried something like

```
A_names = tuple([str(var) for var in A])
```

but this did not work.

Comment: Please [edit] your question make format the code. It is unreadable.

Comment: are your asking if a variable is able to know its name? Or, if you will, if a value knows the name of the variable holding it? (speaking in a non pythonic way)

Comment: Why would you want to do this? If you need to access the second element of `A`, rather than writing `b`, just write `A[1]`.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? If you need to store the variable names, or have dynamic names, it's best to use `dictionaries` instead of `list`/`tuple` combinations

Comment: This is exactly what dictionaries are for, so there's no functionality designed to support the approach you want to take.

Comment: I don't see the point of this but you may use `locals()` to get dictionary of local variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My connection was messed up so I couldn't post this earlier but I believe this solves your problem with out using a dictionary.

```
import inspect

def retrieve_name(var):
    local_vars = inspect.currentframe().f_back.f_locals.items()
    return [var_name for var_name, var_val in local_vars if var_val is var]

a = [1,2,3]
b = [2,4,6,4]
c = [4,6,4]

a_list = (a,b,c)
a_names = []

for x in a_list:
    a_names += (retrieve_name(x)[0])

print a_names
```

outputs `['a', 'b', 'c']`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want dynamic/accessible names, you need to use a dictionary.

Here is an implementation with a dictionary:

```
my_variables = {'a': [1,2,3,...],
                'b': [2,4,6,4,...],
                'c': [4,6,4,...]}

my_variable_names = my_variables.keys()

for name in my_variable_names:
    print(my_variables[name])
```

Comment: Hah, thanks! I was telling myself to change them and then completely forgot.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with what you are asking is that doing `A = (a, b, c)` does not assign the variables "a", "b" and "c" to the tuple `A`.  Rather, you are creating a new reference to each of the objects referred to by those names.

For example, if I did `A = (a,)`, a tuple with a single object.  I haven't assigned the variable "a".  Instead, a reference is created at position 0 in the tuple object.  That reference is to the same object referred to by the name `a`.

```
>>> a = 1
>>> b = 2
>>> A = (a, b)
>>> A
(1, 2)
>>> a = 3
>>> A
(1, 2)
```

Notice that assigning a new value to `a` does not change the value in the tuple at all.

Now, you could use the `locals()` or `globals()` dictionaries and look for values that match those in `A`, but there's no guarantee of accuracy since you can have multiple names referring to the same value and you won't know which is which.

```
>>> for key, val in locals().items():
    if val in A:
        print(key, val)


('a', 1)
('b', 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just out of academic interest:

```
dir() will give you a list of the variables currently visible,
locals() gives the list of local variables
globals() (guess)
```

Note that some unexpected variables will show up (starting and ending in __), which are already defined by Python.

Answer (score 0):

```
A = {'a' : [1,2,3,...],
     'b' : [2,4,6,4,...],
     'c' : [4,6,4,...]}

A_names = A.keys()

for name in A_names:
    print(A[name])
```

Then you can always add a new value to the dictionary by saying:

```
A.update({'d' : [3,6,3,8,...], 'e' : [1,7,2,2,...]})
```

Alternatively, you can change the value of an item by going:

```
A.update({'a' : [1,3,2,...]})
```

To print a specific value, you can just type:

```
print(A['c'])
```